# Extracting object item every 5 seconds in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of quotes and i want to select a random quote and display it every 5 second. So far i've implemented it as follows,

```
//HTML
<div >
  {{ randomQ.quote }} / {{ randomQ.author }}
</div> 

//TS
  public quotes: Quotes[] = [
    {quote:'Q1',author:'A1},
    {quote:'Q2',author:'A2'},
    {quote:'Q3',author:'A3'},
    {quote:'Q4',author:'A4'},

  ];
  public index:number = 0;
  randomQ: Quotes = this.quotes[0];

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.randomQuote();
    }, 5000);
  }
  randomQuote(){
    this.randomQ  = this.quotes[(this.index++)%this.quotes.length];
  }
```

But i worry about when the `index` crosses the limit range of `number` this will crash. Also this seems too many lines of code for simple function.

How do implement this?

Comment: I think you could get the random element a bit easier, [see here how](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)

Comment: I can't see any other possible improvements. Basically you have your collection, your element bound to html and your piece of code that will reset it every 5 seconds. It's the minimum you need anyway

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [Math.random(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)) API to get a random number

```js
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.timeout = setInterval(() => {
      this.randomQ = this.getRandomQuote(this.quotes);
    }, 5000);
  }

  private getRandomQuote(quotes: Quote[]): Quote {
    // Maybe use Math.random to get random number
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    return quotes[randomNumber];
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }
```